Why can't the slope be greater than 1 in regression to the mean for married couples' intelligence?
Consider the following example I read in Daniel Kahneman's book:

Highly intelligent women tend to marry men who are less intelligent than they are.

Kahneman argues that (slightly reworded for clarity)

If men and women on average do not differ in intelligence and the correlation between the intelligence of spouses is less than perfect, this is inevitable.

Consider the regression line of the plot having women's IQs as the x-axis and their husbands' IQs as the y-axis.
What I am imagining is the plot and the line y = x in the middle. The regression line has its slope < 1 and thus highly intelligent women tend to marry less intelligent men.
But, why can't the slope be > 1? I assume that this might not be so because the distribution of intelligence of men and women might differ. (I don't understand why - just a guess)
If it's so, why not? Since we are considering married people only, it's possible that highly intelligent women don't marry at all and if they do - only to more intelligent men.
I guess the assumption is that the distributions of intelligence of married women and men do not differ.
This is just my attempt to the question—which still remains—why can't the slope > 1?

The slope definitely can exceed 1, because it depends on both the correlation and the relative standard deviations of the two (marginal) populations.  You have to interpret "do not differ in intelligence" as meaning more than "have the same mean:" it also has to comprise "have the same standard deviation."  Excellent analyses and discussions of these concepts can be found in Galton's work in the 1870's and 1880's.

@whuber OK, so basically if two distributions have the same standard deviation then slope $\leq 1$ always. (because ChatGPT says that slope = $r \cdot {\sigma_y} / {\sigma_x}$ where $-1 \leq r \leq 1$) But, why then do standard deviations have to be equal? I guess it's the assumption that married men and women have same IQ distributions?

@whuber Please forgive this follow-up comment, but could you please confirm if my reasoning is correct?

The distribution of IQ is mean 100 and standard deviation 15, and is assumed to not differ much for different sub populations like men or women. (It can differ however, the frequency of marriage might differ between men and women with different IQ, but the the argument assumes that there is no large difference)

I interpret Kahneman as saying that you don't need to resort to theories about women marrying down if the correlation between husband and wife IQ is imperfect. But I suspect he was not precise in stating his assumptions about the gender-specific variance of IQ in a book aimed at a broad audience.
You can show it like this. The equations corresponding to the assumption are:
\begin{aligned}
Y_{H} &= \alpha + \varepsilon_H \\
Y_{W} &= \alpha + \varepsilon_W \\
\mathtt{E}[\varepsilon_H] = \mathtt{E}[\varepsilon_W] & = 0 \\
\mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_H)=\mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_W) &= \sigma^2 \\
\mathtt{Corr}\{ \varepsilon_H,\varepsilon_W \} = \rho &< 1
\end{aligned}
Each IQ is a constant plus a random number drawn from a distribution with a mean of zero and the same variance.
In a regression of $Y_H$ on $Y_W$, the slope coefficient is
$$ \beta = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ Y_H,Y_W \}}{\mathtt{Var} \{ Y_W\}} =\frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \alpha + \varepsilon_H,\alpha + \varepsilon_W \}}{\mathtt{Var} \{ \alpha + \varepsilon_W \}}=\frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{\varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\mathtt{Var} \{\varepsilon_W \}} = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sigma^2}.
$$
Since $$\rho = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sqrt{\mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_H) \cdot \mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_W)}} = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sigma^2},$$
we can rewrite the slope coefficient as
$$ \beta = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\rho \cdot \sigma^2}{\sigma^2}=\rho <1
$$
If we relax the assumption of equal variances and let \begin{aligned}
\mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_H)= \sigma_H^2 \ne  \sigma_W^2 = \mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_W),  \\
\end{aligned}
then things don't work out so nicely. The slope coefficient has a different numerator:
$$ \beta' = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sigma_W^2}.
$$
Since now $$\rho' = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sqrt{\mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_H) \cdot \mathtt{Var}(\varepsilon_W)}} = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sigma_W \cdot \sigma_H},$$
then
$$ \beta' = \frac{\mathtt{Cov} \{ \varepsilon_H, \varepsilon_W \}}{\sigma_W^2} =  \frac{\rho' \cdot \sigma_W \cdot \sigma_H}{\sigma_W^2} = \rho' \cdot \left( \frac{\sigma_H}{\sigma_W} \right).
$$
Below is a plot of $\beta$ as a function of $\rho$ and the husband-wife variance ratio. As you move along the x-axis, you get more husbands in the tails relative to their wives: more geniuses, but also more of whatever the polite term for the opposite of genius might be. As you move up the y-axis, husbands and wives become more correlated.

Each pair of ratios and correlations on a curve yields a $\beta$ corresponding to the curve's label. When $\frac{\sigma_H}{\sigma_W} \le 1$ it's impossible to get a $\beta>1$. As the ratio creeps above 1, high values of $\rho$ begin to allow $\beta>1$. For example, if the variance ratio is $2$, any correlation stronger than $0.5$ will give a slope greater than $1$.

I think you are plotting the wrong thing. If you look at a fit of wife_iq vs. husband_iq, then we could well get a slope of 1, or less than 1, or more than 1. But what Kahnemann says is that highly intelligent women marry men who are less intelligent. He could equally well have switched "men" and "women" or looked at "very unintelligent" instead of "highly intelligent". Indeed, he could have substituted any trait where there is less than perfect correlation and equal means.
Kahnemann says nothing (at least, in what you quoted) about the slope of the line for the whole sample.
What Kahnemann would have you do, though, is look just at the highest values of either axis.

I believe the conclusion "this is inevitable" is a particular implication of regression to the mean.  Otherwise, how do you explain this phrase of Kahneman's?

The slope of a linear regression is
$$\text{slope} = \rho  \cdot \frac{sd_y}{sd_x}$$
If we assume $sd_y \approx sd_x$ and $\rho<1$, then $\text{slope} < 1$.
See also the question: Effect of switching response and explanatory variable in simple linear regression
The image below might show intuitively how a symmetric situation, does not lead to a slope equal to unity. Especially in left panel, we might feel that it would not make sense for the regression line to have a slope equal to 1.

Another example image is below where the distribution ofen and women is with the same deviations, and we marked the points where '118 < women < 122'. You can see that the conditional distribution for the men is lower. Women with IQ 120 tend to marry men with a lower IQ.

